# How to iterate thru records selected in nested Oracle SQL query and select them in outer select based on certain condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I'm stuck on a problem:

Right now I have a bunch of nested select statements which gives me a set of records:

```
1. KEY_ID       SEQ_DATETTIME   ETR_DATETIME 
2. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_1       08/28/2019 19:15:00 
3. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_2       08/28/2019 23:30:00
4. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_3       08/28/2019 23:45:00
5. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_4       08/29/2019 00:00:00
6. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_5       08/29/2019 00:15:00
7. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_6       08/29/2019 01:00:00
```

In my next outer select statement I want to be able to always keep ETR_SEQ_1. If it's not 'ETR_SEQ_1' then I have to check to see whether or not ETR_DATETIME is greater than 60 minutes from the previous value (ETR_DATETIME - lag(ETR_DATETIME). If it is greater than 60 then I want to keep it, if it is less than 60 then I don't want to keep it.  I need to iterate thru this until I reach the last record with that KEY_ID

So this would be the data:

```
1. KEY_ID   SEQ_DATETTIME   ETR_DATETIME         
2. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_1   08/28/2019 19:15:00
3. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_2   08/28/2019 23:30:00
4. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_3   08/28/2019 23:45:00
5. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_4   08/29/2019 00:00:00
6. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_5   08/29/2019 00:15:00
7. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_6   08/29/2019 01:00:00
```

And this would be the result in the next outer select statement:

```
1. KEY_ID   SEQ_DATETTIME   ETR_DATETIME         
2. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_1   08/28/2019 19:15:00
3. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_2   08/28/2019 23:30:00
4. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_6   08/29/2019 01:00:00
```

(It's not always 6 records per key_id, could be more could be less, and there are other key_id records)

I then continue to use the data in outer select statements.

Please help I have no idea how to iterate thru this.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't iterate in SQL you manipulate sets

Comment: So the Keep is not based on 30 mins from the prior one but from the last non drop one -- coorrect

Comment: yes Hogan that is right, the keep is not based on 60 (not 30) mins from prior, but from the last "non drop" record.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * from (SELECT T.*, 
Case when (ETR_DATETIME - lag(ETR_DATETIME) over (partition by key_id order by ETR_DATETIME) * 1440 > 60 
then 1 
else 0 end as diff
From (your_inner_query) t where t.status = 'KEEP')
Where SEQ_DATETTIME = 'ETR_SEQ_1' or NVL(diff,1) = 1
```

Cheers!!

Comment: see my comment above you only want to check the timestamp on the last one that was not dropped

Comment: Hogan is correct, I have to check the timestamp on the last one that was NOT DROP.  So on line 7 I have to check it against line 3

Comment: Ok. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I cannot use t.status = 'KEEP' from your solution.  I think my example data may not be clear, there is no status column in my data.  I just added that to illustrate which rows I expected as results.  I have to figure out how to determine which rows to keep and drop.

Comment: Please update the sample data so that i can update my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you, I have updated it.  There is no status column.   I always keep ETR_SEQ_1 and then I have to check whether the ETR_DATETIME from the current row is greater than 60 from the previous row.  If it is less than 60 from the previous row, then the record is not selected until I end up with only records where the ETR_DATETIME from the current record is greater than 60 from the previous.  I know in other languages there is recursion but I don't know how to do it in a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to check to see whether or not ETR_DATETIME is greater than 60 minutes from the previous value (ETR_DATETIME - lag(ETR_DATETIME). If it is greater than 60 then I want to keep it, if it is less than 60 then I don't want to keep it.

You want to use `lag()`, as in:

```
select t.*
From (select t.*,
             lag(ETR_DATETIME) over (partition by key_id order by ETR_DATETIME) as prev_edt
      from t
     ) t
where prev_edt is null or prev_edt < etr_datetime - interval '60' minute
```

Comment: I don't think this works -- the compare has to be against the prior column that was considered good -- not just the prior column. (see my answer for an intermediate state that is needed before this query would work)

Comment: Yes the compare has to be against the prior column that was considered "good".  but how do I get to that intermediate state?

Comment: @Gary . . . That is not what this question says.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with a clear description of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this table:

```
1. KEY_ID       SEQ_DATETTIME   ETR_DATETIME         VIR_TS              STATUS  
2. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_1       08/28/2019 19:15:00  08/28/2019 19:15:00 KEEP 
3. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_2       08/28/2019 23:30:00  08/28/2019 19:15:00 KEEP
4. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_3       08/28/2019 23:45:00  08/28/2019 19:15:00 DROP
5. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_4       08/29/2019 00:00:00  08/28/2019 19:15:00 DROP
6. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_5       08/29/2019 00:15:00  08/28/2019 19:15:00 DROP
7. 2002707959   ETR_SEQ_6       08/29/2019 01:00:00  08/29/2019 01:00:00 KEEP
```

Here you only have to compare against VIR_TS column right?
The trick is to generate the VIR_TS column and then use LAG() on that column as Tajash's answer